# Why does this iteration to insert items into a binary tree fail?

Tags: c

```
node_t *insert_node(node_t *root, node_t *new) {
       node_t *curr;
       curr = root;

       if(root == NULL) {
          root = new;   
          return root;
       } else {

           while(curr) {
               printf("%s", curr->name);
               if(strcmp(curr->name, new->name)<0) {           
                   curr = root->left;

               } else {
                   curr = root->right;

               }
           }
           printf("%s", curr);
           curr = new;
           printf("%s\n", curr->name);
       }   `enter code here`

       return root;
}

tree_t *insert_tree(tree_t *tree, void *line1, void *line2){
    node_t *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->name = line1;
    new->movie = line2;
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    tree->root = recursive_insert(tree->root, new);






    return tree;
}

static node_t *recursive_insert(node_t *root, node_t *new) {
    if(root==NULL){
        return new;
    } else  if((strcmp(root->name, new->name))<0) {
        root->left = recursive_insert(root->left, new);
    } else {
        root->right = recursive_insert(root->right, new);
    } 
    return root;
}
```

I've been working on this for the last 50 hours or so just to get it to work.

The problem seems to be in the `while` loop in the `if` statement.

`curr = root-> left;` and `curr = root->right` isn't updating the nodes properly as intended.

To check if it does update or not I have inserted `printf` statement inside the `while` loop.

And it prints out just the same thing.

Which makes `strcmp` compare strings with the same string over and over again.

I think this could be something to do with properties of structure but I don't know what.

the bottom two functions implement insertion to tree through recursion

ive been trying to implement recursive insertion with iterative insertion

because

when the datafiles are large recursion fails

the recursion works without any errors

the top function and the bottom two functions are meant to do the same thing

the bottom two works fine

but the top one with while loop it doesn't

can anyone please compare the two version for incorrectness!!

Comment: Among other problems, you're probably assigning the same pointer to `->name` all the time, leading all the names to point to the same string. That's in code you haven't posted though.

Comment: All this does: `curr = new;` is save the value of the `new` pointer to the local variable `curr`, Your tree remains unchanged.

Comment: I wish I had time to explain how [this algorithm works](http://pastebin.com/nPeMw2q1)

Comment: @WhozCraig that's the way I'd do it, but it's not immediately apparent to many people how it works.

Comment: WhozCraig wow i couldn't believe my eyes when it worked with your code i wish i could prgramme like you

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strcmp(curr->name, new->name)<0) {           
    curr = root->left;
} else {
    curr = root->right;
}
```

You are assigning always the same value... maybe you meant `curr = curr->left` and `curr = curr->right`?

Comment: and of course in the last line `return curr;` instead of `return root;`

Answer (score 1):

There are two big problems. The first is that you use `root->left` and `root->right`, which won't advance further down your tree but stay stuck at the children of the root node. This will cause an infinite loop if your root has children, and it won't insert any new ones if the root has no children.

However, this isn't even a problem *yet*, since you don't correctly insert anything (so the root will never have children). You assign `new` into `curr`, perhaps thinking that that will add the node to the tree. `curr` is a local variable; the pointers that you're interested in updating are `curr->left` and `curr->right`.

Of course, when your while loop ends, `curr` is null, so `curr->left` and `curr->right` don't even exist.

So, the fixes are as follows:

1. Change `root->left` and `root->right` to `curr->left` and `curr->right`.
2. First check if the children are null. If not, then set the working node to the child and keep looping. Otherwise, save the node in the tree and quit the loop somehow.

   ```
   if (curr->left) {
       curr = curr->left;
   } else {
       curr->left = new;
       return curr->left; // we return the newly inserted node immediately
   }
   ```

Your recursive version works because you *assign* the result of the recursive call into `root->left` or `root->right`. Your recursive function returns the new node when the `root` node passed in is null. So you're assigning the child pointer to the new node.

Also, to clear up the confusion that you had about `root` and `curr`: in the recursive version, there's no "working" node; that is, each recursive call is dealing with its own "root." The root is not the root of the whole tree, but in fact the root node of the subtree pointed to by the left or right pointer of the parent node. In the loop version, instead of passing the child node into the next recursive call, we assign the pointer to the child node into the "working" node `curr`.